# Changing Raycaster position dynamically

Tags: jquery, three.js, draggable, raycasting

I have a canvas, inside that I have several cubes. I use Raycaster to  select them and change their colors. But the canvas is inside of a `draggable` object and when I move around I cannot change the colors, the color changing works in the original position. I think I also have to change the dimensions of the Raycaster. How can I do that?

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/MAEvS/191/).

Comment: onDocumentMouseDown() is not even getting called after the drag event. I don't think this is a three.js problem.

Comment: The question is how to resolve it then..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to change a code as follows:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var x = event.offsetX == undefined ? event.layerX : event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY == undefined ? event.layerY : event.offsetY;

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
    vector.set( ( x / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1, - ( y / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
    vector.unproject( camera );

    raycaster.ray.set( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
...
```