# three.js raycaster with dynamic canvas position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, three.js

i currently have a three.js scene in a twitter bootstrap environment, so the renderer.domelement can resize and change its position dependent on screen resolution, browser window size and so on.

Now i have problems using the three.js raycaster to intersect objects in this scene. When the page loads and the scene is shown on the screen the raycaster works fine, but when i scroll the browser window and/or resize it so that the scene is at a different position in the browser window, the intersection of objects doesn't work anymore.

i have no idea how to fix this issue...does someone have an idea how i can fix this?

This is how my Raycaser aktually looks like:

```
var container = document.getElementById( 'view' );

///Raycaster///

    var projector = new THREE.Projector();

    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

        var mouseX = ( ( event.clientX - container.offsetLeft ) / container.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        var mouseY = - ( ( event.clientY - container.offsetTop ) / container.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0.5);
        projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {

            // do something

            var origin = raycaster.ray.origin.clone();
            console.log(origin);

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Look [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862229/changing-raycaster-position-dynamically/27885851#27885851)

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
let canvasBounds = this.engine.context.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
this.mouse.x = ((event.clientX - canvasBounds.left) / (canvasBounds.right - canvasBounds.left)) * 2 - 1;
this.mouse.y = -((event.clientY - canvasBounds.top) / (canvasBounds.bottom - canvasBounds.top)) * 2 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution for solving problems with re-sizing your browser window is adding a `onWindowResize` handler.

So for example:

```
/**
 * Resize event handler adjust renderer size and resetting camera's aspect
 */
function onWindowResize()
{
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
```

And add the listener like this:

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm fine with the automatic resizing of the canvas, it still works. My problem is to make the raycaster still work when the user scrolls the site.