# Click object in THREE.js with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

I have tried many solutions without success: it only detects on plane and wrong position of cube.

Because of angular event be easy to call.

1.Add a tag in html.

```
<div (click)="onClickCanvas($event)">
```

2.Add a function in typescript like this:

```
onClickCanvas(event) {
  let intersects;
  mouse['x'] = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse['y'] = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  if (intersects.length !== 0) console.log(intersects[0]['object'])
}
```

3.I use the **PerspectiveCamera** in `THREE.js`.

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)

camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 50;
camera.position.z = 45;
```

4.Let me show you a [video](https://youtu.be/dnlDsuYjXR8).

I am using **OrbitControls** at same time.
But even I don't call the controls it didn't work...

**MY QUESTION IS:**

when I click the object I want to console.log, it never shows!

There's only plane I can see!

I click the sphere or cube didn't happened!

And sometime I click plane it console.log the cube...

Comment: Exactly what are you asking? Make your problem clear. You have not described nor your problem neither what you want to achieve.

Comment: You're right! Sorry this is my first post!

Comment: Maybe it's the common problem to get the wrong 3D coordinates from 2D, when canvas covers only part the window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758834/three-js-2d-mouseclick-to-3d-co-ordinates-using-raycaster/34797945#34797945

Comment: No way!! How can I not find this article!
TANKS for answer! I have try a week for only this problem..
thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

To see what is happening there, you can add some simple object to your scene and position it on click to the point of intersection (`intersections[0].position` iirc). I would expect that is not where you think it is. Here is why:

You are using calculations that are only appropriate when using a fullscreen-canvas element although your canvas seems to be limited in size and not aligned with the page-origin.

So instead of

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)
```

You need to use something like

```
var canvasWidth = renderer.domElement.offsetWidth;
var canvasHeight = renderer.domElement.offsetHeight;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 1, 1000)
```

And instead of

```
mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
```

You need to compute these values relative to the canvas. The x and y values for the mouse need to be normalized coordinates. This means the left edge of the canvas has `x === -1` and the right edge `x === 1`. The same goes for top (`y === 1`) and bottom (`y === -1`).

For this you can do something like

```
var rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
var dx = ev.clientX - rect.x;
var dy = ev.clientY - rect.y;

mouse.x = (dx / rect.width) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = (dy / rect.height) * 2 + 1;
```